# Como colar texto da área de transferência no vim?

Tags: vim

Pesquisando o *cheat sheet* de alguns lugares, descobri como ver a área de transferência (os *registers*) no vim, `:reg`.

[image: saída do console para o comando :reg]

Porém, não consegui utilizar esses registros, mesmo utilizando os comandos demonstrados nos sites.

---

- Como faço para colar um texto da área de transferência?
- Como se seleciona e se copia algo do próprio vim?

> **EDIT** -> Textos copiados de outros programas surgem na lista de registros como um *quarto item*, e terminam não sendo acessíveis pelo *paste* simples do vim.

- Como ter acesso aos outros textos salvos nos registros?

Comment: Só uma observação: os registros do vim, e as operações de yank e paste normalmente não tem relação com o clipboard do OS. Para integração, veja esse link http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Como faço para colar um texto da área de transferência?

[Normalmente uso a tecla <kbd>p</kbd> para colar após o cursor. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> para colar antes](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste) (ou ainda <kbd>P</kbd>, maiúsculo).

> Como se seleciona e se copia algo do próprio vim?

Sem usar recursos gráficos, usa-se o seguinte:

- <kbd>y</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> copia a linha do cursor;
- <kbd>y</kbd> + número + seta copia *número* linhas na direção da seta. Se for para cima, copia as *número* linhas acima. Para baixo, as *número* linhas abaixo.

> Como ter acesso aos outros textos salvos nos registros?

Primeiro você precisa definir os registros. Vou usar seus exemplos do *print*. De qualquer forma, para definir um registro `r`, usamos <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>. Use a seguir <kbd>y</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> para copiar a linha atual para o registro `a`.

Para concatenar um valor já existente em `a`, use <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (sim, maiúsculo).

Para colar o conteúdo do registro `a`, use <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>.

Lembrando que todas as operações devem ser feitas fora do modo de inserção para funcionar.

---

#### No modo de inserção

O bom e velho <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> para Windows, clique do botão do meio do mouse para Linux e <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> para Mac colam o texto da área de transferência no Vim.

Comment: lembrando que no modo de inserção `Ctrl + V` só obedece quebras de linha corretamente se usar `:set paste` antes

Comment: costumo selecionar texto para de 2 maneiras: (1) 'y' + teclas de movimento (setas, w, b, etc) e (2) 'v' + teclas de movimento + 'y', que é mais versátil: por exemplo, 'v' + 2 vezes seta à direita + 'y' copia 3 caracteres, que podem ser colado com 'p' (puristas provavelmente usariam as teclas hjkl como teclas de movimento, mas isso é desnecessário)

Answer (score 0):

Se estive usando Linux você tem uma "área de transferência a mais" chamada de visual selection, qualquer seleção com o mouse coloca o conteúdo selecionado na mesma, para colar esse conteúdo no modo insert faça:

```
Ctrl-r *
```

Agora se copiar no browser por exemplo usando Ctrl-c o conteúdo também vai para a Área de transferência padrão, no modo insert insira este conteúdo com:

```
Ctrl-r +
```

No modo normal você pode inserir esses conteúdos com:

```
"*p
"+p
```

Para coloar esses conteúdos nas respectivas "Áreas de transferência", selecione o trecho desejado e faça:

```
 "*y
 "+y
```

Um problema comum a usuários novados do vim é quando tenta-se copiar um trecho para sobrescrever outro, ao apagar o conteúdo de destino ele sobrescreve o que foi copiado, mas não o registro 0 "zero",  que contém o último trecho copiado.

Pra colar o que foi copiado sobre um trecho que acabou de ser deletado faça: (em Modo Insert)

```
Ctrl-r 0
```

Por fim você pode copiar de ourto arquivo do vim ou mesmo um trecho diferente do mesmo arquivo para registros que vão de 'a' a 'z' . Tipo, seleciona um trecho e digita `"ay`, ou ainda deletar uma linha adicionando seu conteúdo ao registro `a`, faça:

```
"Add
```

Ao usar uma letra maiúscula o vim "adiciona" o conteúdo ao registro sem sobrescreve-lo.

No modo global podemos por exemplo adicionar todas as linhas contendo a palavra 'ERROR' para o registro `a` de modo que podemos cola-lo em ouro trecho ou arquivo do vim:

```
:g/ERROR/normal! "Ayy
```

Pra garantir você deve limpar o conteúdo do registro 'a' fazendo

```
 qaq
```

O tema pode se estender muito pois os registros do vim vão além, aconselho uma lida com calma em `:h registers`. mas seguem algumas pérolas:

```
Ctrl-r / .................. insere a última busca (Modo Insert)
Ctrl-r : .................. insere o último comando
Ctrl-r % .................. insere o nome do arquivo
:put a  ................... insere o conteúdo do registro 'a'
```